# Make custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am new to android development and i want to learn how to make custom views in android.The view which i wanna make is something like this:

[image]

The app will have a button which shows up menu items. I don't want to use navigation drawer in my app so I thought of doing something like this.Please help me out in achieving this.

P.S. - I don't want to use a library,I wanna learn by myself,so any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Create a layout like this with transparent background and inflate it when plus button clicked or you can use fragment

Comment: Please can you give me examples???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making such kind of views you can also use `third party` open source library 
i.e. https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu

and this kind of views are called `arc menu views`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create custom View then follow these steps it will create an example of custom View.
**Steps**

1. Right click on package
2. select new -> click on other
3. select android -> click on android object
4. select custom View -> next -> next -> finish.
5. insert this created layout in your MainActivity as..

   setContentView(R.layout.sample_my_view);